# MS Project and VBA IFF FORMULA

Tags: vba, ms-project

I have to make in Ms-Project and VBA something like that but in a Formula:

```
If Number2=1 then 
    Duration=4
Else
    Duration=5
End if
```

I have this code:

```
CustomFieldSetFormula FieldID:=pjCustomTaskDuration1, Formula:="Iff(Number2=1;Duration=4;Duration=5)"
CustomFieldPropertiesEx FieldID:=pjCustomTaskDuration1, Attribute:=pjFieldAttributeFormula, SummaryCalc:=pjCalcFormula, GraphicalIndicators:=False, AutomaticallyRolldownToAssn:=False
CustomFieldPropertiesEx FieldID:=pjCustomTaskDuration1, Attribute:=pjFieldAttributeNone, SummaryCalc:=pjCalcNone, GraphicalIndicators:=False, AutomaticallyRolldownToAssn:=False
```

Comment: @RandomDownVoter: Why the down-vote? Down votes should be explained, especially with new users. This is a reasonably well-formed and on-topic question.

Answer (score 1):

You were close. The formula you need is this: `IIf([Number2]=1,[Duration4],[Duration5])`. Note that the function is called **Inline If**, therefore the abbreviation is IIf, not IFf.